# Prayer and tashahud

Tags: prophet-muhammad

In the tashahud we recite peace be upon you o Muhammed  and Allah's blessings and mercy. Is this not praying to muhammad saws as we are directly praising him in the tashahud? 
Can you explain this please.

Comment: How is it praying to Muhammad (SAW) when we're literally asking (praying to) Allah to bestow His blessings upon him? And in which part are we directly (or indirectly) praising him in the Tashahud?

Answer (score 1):

The [Tashahud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tashahhud) in Arabic according to the two schools (the *Hanafi* and the *Hanbali*) and its recitation which is attributed to *Abdullah ibn Masud*:

> التَّحِيَّاتُ لِلّٰهِ وَالصَّلَوَاتُ وَالطَّيِّبَاتُ، اَلسَّلَامُ
>   عَلَيْكَ أَيُّهَا النَّبِيُّ وَرَحْمَةُ اللهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ،
>   اَلسَّلَامُ عَلَيْنَا وَ عَلٰى عِبَادِ اللهِ الصَّالِحِيْنَ، أَشْهَدُ
>   أَنْ لَا إِلٰهَ إِلَّا اللهُ، وَأَشْهَدُ أَنَّ مُحَمَّدًا عَبْدُهُ وَ
>   رَسُوْلُهُ

The translation:

> "Salutations to God and prayers and good deeds. **Peace be upon you, O Prophet**, and the mercy of God and his blessings. Peace be on us and on the righteous servants of God. I bear witness that there is no god but Allah, and I bear witness that Muhammad is His servant and His messenger."

I have bolded what you are asking about in your question regarding the Tashahud.

As you can see, the peace we are asking Allah of, is what would be **upon** (which is equal to **on** in English) Muhammad (SAW), not **to** for example.

[Be upon somebody (*formal*)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upon) meaning according to Cambridge Dictionary:

> to be something that someone will experience or have to deal with soon.

In the Tashahud, it is clear what is the *something* (peace) and who is the *someone* (Muhammad (SAW)).

---

[See here for the meaning of each word in the Tashahud](https://muslimcentral.com/abdul-nasir-jangda-meaning-tashahhud/)